# How to properly set "key" in React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Here are the three React components:**

*Product.jsx*

```
import statusMap from "../statusMap";

function Product(props) {
  const {
    prod_id: id,
    prod_name: title,
    prod_status: status,
    prod_price: price,
    prod_oldprice: oldPrice,
  } = props;

  let oldPriceChecker = (oldPriceValue) => {
    if (oldPriceValue) {
      let oldPriceStr = oldPriceValue + " zł";
      return oldPriceStr;
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  };

  let statusChecker = (value) => {
    if (value != undefined && value != "") {
      let string = value;
      let array = string.split(",");
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = statusMap.get(array[i]);
      }

      return array.map((n) => <div className="status">{n}</div>);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-image">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" key={id} />
          <div className="status_container">{statusChecker(status)}</div>
        </div>
        <div className="card-content">
          <span className="card-title">{title}</span>
          <hr className="card_hr" />
          <p className="card_price">{price} zł</p>
          <div className="card_price old_price">
            {oldPriceChecker(oldPrice)}
          </div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export { Product };
```

*Products.jsx*

```
import { Product } from "./Product";

function Products(props) {
  const { products = [] } = props;

  return (
    <div className="products">
      {products.length ? (
        products.map((product) => (
          <Product key={product.prod_id} {...product} />
        ))
      ) : (
        <h4 className="products_error">Nothing found</h4>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export { Products };
```

*Filter.jsx*

```
import statusMap from "../statusMap";

const Filter = ({ values, value, onChange }) => (
  <div className="row filter_container">
    <h3 className="filter_title">Sortować według</h3>
    <div className="filter_wrapper">
      {values.map((n) => (
        <label>
          <input
            className="with-gap"
            type="radio"
            onChange={() => onChange(n)}
            checked={value === n}
          />
          <span>{statusMap.get(n)}</span>
        </label>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);

export { Filter };
```

***I finished the project, but the following errors continue to hang in the console:***

***[Error1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2epg.png)***

***[Error2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur0BA.png)***

***[Error3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ncbm.png)***

**Please tell me how to remove them**

***I have read the documentation on the key parameter in detail. You may notice that I have tried to set the key values, however this does not clear up the errors in the console.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to set a unique key to each element while we return from map function of array. So you can try this one;

```
  let statusChecker = (value) => {
    if (value != undefined && value != "") {
      let string = value;
      let array = string.split(",");
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = statusMap.get(array[i]);
      }

      return array.map((n) => <div key={n} className="status">{n}</div>);
    }
  };
```

I assume your `status` item is unique in the array you defined. Care the `key={n}` in following;

```
return array.map((n) => <div key={n} className="status">{n}</div>);
```

Comment: You are right, one of the errors is gone, but what about `<h3 className="filter_title">Sortować według</h3>` in Filter.jsx? There we have a non-changeable title

Comment: In Filter.jsx you need to follow same practice for `<label>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a unique key to each returned element from Array.map function.

the Array.map function have three parameters :

```
Array.map((element,index,array)=>{return ...}
```

read more about array function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) :

Knowing that the key should be unique you can do like this :

```
return array.map((element,index) => <div key={index} className="status">{n}</div>);
```